# VSCode: Command "Run active file in active terminal" doesn't work with bash

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, git-bash

I have a simple testfile named newfile.sh with this line of code:

```
echo "Hello Bangkok!"
```

If I run this with typing in the bash console

```
bash myfile.sh
```

it works:

[image]

But if I go with ctrl+shift+p to the commands and select "Run active file in active terminal" it doesn't work. Output:

[image]

The $ sign is missing in front of bash, it adds a colon to the command bash and it removes the backslash from the file path. This logically leads to the error "command not found".

Anyone an idea how to fix this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I installed the extension "Code Runner" and added the line `"code-runner.runInTerminal": true` to settings.json. Now I have a shortcut to run the file in the bash terminal.